# calculating seasonal range in r for a number of years

Tags: r

I have a data frame of daily temperature measurements spanning 20 years. I would like to calculate the annual range in the data series for each year (i.e. end up with 20 values, representing the range for each year). Example data:

```
begin_date = as.POSIXlt("1990-01-01", tz = "GMT")
dat = data.frame(dt = begin_date + (0:(20*365)) * (86400))
dat = within(dat, {speed = runif(length(dt), 1, 10)})
```

I was thinking of writing a loop which goes through each year and then calculate the range, but was hoping there was another solution.

I think the best way forward would be to have the maximum and minimum values for each year and then calculate the range from that. Can anyone suggest a method to do this without writing a loop to go through each year individually?

Comment: apply or sapply functions?  i'm sure there's a great functional, one line approach to it.

Comment: Try `library(dplyr);dat %>% group_by(year=year(dt)) %>% summarise= Max= max(speed), Min=min(speed))` Or may be `dat %>% group_by(year=year(dt)) %>% summarise(Range= toString(round(range(speed),2)))`

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
library(dplyr)
dat %>% 
    group_by(year=year(dt)) %>% 
    summarise(Range=diff(range(speed)))
```

Or

```
library(data.table)
setDT(dat)[, list(Range=diff(range(speed))), year(dt)]
```

Or

```
aggregate(speed~cbind(year=year(dt)), dat, function(x) diff(range(x)))
```